# Retrieve generic type information with reflection

Tags: java, reflection

Let's suppose I have these classes,

```
public class StringObjectKeyValueStore<V> extends AbstractObjectStore<V>
        implements KeyValueStore<String, V> {
}

public abstract class AbstractObjectStore<V> {
     private final Class<V> type;
     public AbstractObjectStore() {
        this.type = (Class<V>) ((ParameterizedType) getClass()
            .getGenericSuperclass()).getActualTypeArguments()[0];
}
```

Which I use it like this:

```
KeyValueStore<String,Friend> friendstore = new StringObjectKeyValueStore();
```

In the `AbstractObjectStore` how do I get the `com.xzvf.models.Friend` without modifying the `AbstractObjectStore` constructor and passing `Class<V> clazz` there.

From my debugging this part

```
((ParameterizedType) getClass()
                .getGenericSuperclass()).getActualTypeArguments()[0];
```

Just returns `name = {java.lang.String@1452} "V"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. It's impossible.

First, [`Class#getGenericSuperclass()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getGenericSuperclass%28%29)

> Returns the Type representing the direct superclass of the entity
>   (class, interface, primitive type or void) represented by this Class.

So for `StringObjectKeyValueStore`, the direct superclass is `AbstractObjectStore`, a `ParameterizedType`, because it is parameterized with a type variable. `ParamerizedType` has a method [`getActualTypeArguments`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/ParameterizedType.html#getActualTypeArguments%28%29) which

> Returns an array of Type objects representing the actual type arguments to this type.

For your example, ie. `StringObjectKeyValueStore`, the generic superclass is `AbstractObjectStore`, which was given a single type arguments in the `StringObjectKeyValueStore` class declaration,

```
public class StringObjectKeyValueStore<V> extends AbstractObjectStore<V>
```

ie. the type variable `V`. So, for

```
KeyValueStore<String,Friend> = new StringObjectKeyValueStore();
```

this code

```
((ParameterizedType) getClass()
            .getGenericSuperclass()).getActualTypeArguments()[0];
```

will return a `TypeVariableImpl` object for the type variable `V`.

If your declaration was

```
public class StringObjectKeyValueStore<V> extends AbstractObjectStore<String>
                                                                   // ^ see here
```

then

```
((ParameterizedType) getClass()
            .getGenericSuperclass()).getActualTypeArguments()[0];
```

would return the `Class` object for `String` since `String` is the actual type argument you used.

Answer (score 1):

The only way this is workable is if you subclass `StringObjectKeyValueStore`:

```
class FriendStore extends StringObjectKeyValueStore<Friend>{}
```

The you can resolve `V` for a particular type, such as `KeyValueStore`, using [TypeTools](https://github.com/jhalterman/typetools) (which I authored):

```
Class<?> v = TypeResolver.resolveRawArguments(KeyValueStore.class, FriendStore.class)[1];
assert v == Friend.class;
```